# ImportError : No module named options.pipeline_options

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

[This is the error screenshot, click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75mfp.png)
i want to run a wordcount program using dataflow in python 2.7 on gcloud SDK

i have used the path to import the PipelineOptions,

Here are two approaches-
1.from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
  from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

2.from apache_beam.pipeline import PipelineOptions
  from apache_beam.pipeline import SetupOptions

but it still show 'ImportError: No module named options.pipeline_options' in both of the approaches which i try.
there is any solution in apache_beam or in python 2.7 ?

Comment: How are you setting up the dependency on apache_beam?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions for the Python Quickstart? https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/

Comment: Yes, i have followed all instruction and steps as described on -  beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py –

Comment: For creating pipeline , I have installed apache_beam using command prompt and use its wordcount program which have the following path "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\examples\wordcount.py" and the import module have the following path "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\options\pipeline_options.py". I have tried all google documentation and apache_beam documentation also.

Comment: Could you share the exact steps you followed? It looks like you installed apache-beam (using pip) globally and not in a virtual environment.

How are you alternating between two approaches? Are you modifying installed files?

Comment: I have used two methods for installing. These are - 1. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python     2. https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/

Comment: Did you use  ```save_main_session``` parameter?